# Rails - Caching external HTTP calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, caching

My Rails app has to make a massive amount of external http calls. Sometimes, redundant http calls to handle a request. So, I'm looking for a way to cache external http calls. The way should use memory to keep cached data. Please help.

Comment: Check out http://www.rubyops.net/caching-external-http-requests-with-vcr-in-rack.

Comment: I think, VRC stores cached data on YAML files. Anyway, thank you so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like you could just use Rails caching to accomplish this, though I haven't actually tested it.

```
results = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key) do  # You could use a unique URL as part of the cache key
  # HTTP request
  # Return results from processing the response
end
```

More about Rails caching http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html